# How would you find the eccentricity of this conic section?

Tags: calculus, conic-sections, polar-coordinates

$4x^2 - 5y^2 - 16x - 50y + 71 = 0$

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Consider rewriting in standard form first. That should give your $a$ and $b$ lengths for the semi-major and minor axes. If you find those, you'll be nearly done.

Comment: Got it when I did it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting this in standard form we get 
\begin{align*}
4x^2-5y^2-16x-50y+71 &= 4x^2-16x-5y^2-50y+71\\
&=4(x^2-4x)-5(y^2+10y)+71 \\
&= 4(x^2-4x+4)-16-5(y^2+10y+25)+125+71\\
&=4(x-2)^2-5(y+5)^2+180=0\\
&=4(x-2)^2-5(y+5)^2 = -180\\
&=5(y+5)^2-4(x-2)^2=180
\end{align*}
Dividing both sides by $180$ we get $$\frac{(y+6)^2}{36}-\frac{(x-2)^2}{45} = 1$$
This is a hyperbola with $a=6, b=3\sqrt5$ so $c = \sqrt{36+45} = 9$. The eccentricity is given by $\dfrac{c}{a}$. So it is $\dfrac96 = \dfrac32$.